# Balanced Payments - Balanced::BankAccount and invalidation of stored accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, balanced-payments

I am adding Balanced Payments (-v 0.6.0) to an existing system to enable marketplace features, and am running into an issues with the cleanup (invalidation) of a stored Bank Account when a new Bank Account is added/stored to a Customer  Account (we only want sellers in marketplace to have at most one Bank Account active, to reduce complexity).

to make my question simple, here is a simple version of the what we are attempting, and the log response (error)

```
if (!params[:balanced_uri].blank?)
      begin
          @balanced_acctresponse = Balanced::Account.find(params[:balanced_uri])

          bankaccts = Balanced::BankAccount.find(@balanced_acctresponse.bank_accounts_uri)

          bankaccts.invalidate  
      rescue => e
          logger.debug("Balanced Bank Account error :: #{e}")
      end
```

this is generating the following exception

> Balanced Bank Account error :: Balanced::BadRequest(400)::Bad
>   Request:: POST
>   https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/xxxxxx/accounts/xxxxxx/bank_accounts?limit=10&offset=0:
>   request: Missing required field [name]

I'm confused as to what name field is missing.  As defined here http://rubydoc.info/gems/balanced/0.6.0/Balanced/BankAccount there is no name param required for invalidate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you upgrade to the latest version of balanced-ruby (0.7.4). I recommend you then try something like:

```
begin
  @account = Balanced::Account.find(current_user.balanced_account_uri)

  @account.bank_accounts.each do |ba|
    ba.invalidate
  end 
rescue => e
  logger.debug("Balanced Bank Account error :: #{e}")
end
```

This will find the Account instance in Balanced, loop through its bank accounts and invalidate each of them.

NOTE: Account was deprecated about 9 months ago, superseded by Customer. Account will not be in the next API revision.

If you have any other questions, feel free to also drop by #balanced on Freenode IRC. There you can get assistance directly from developers.

Comment: Very appreciative of your comments, I'll make the switch to 0.7.4 and then reattempt

Comment: I can confirm that after the change to 0.7.4, I can properly call invalidate on the Bank_Accounts objs, again thanks for the assistance